# Async List Comprehensions in Python

Tags: python, asynchronous, list-comprehension

Is it possible to do a list comprehension in Python asynchronously? I am trying to make many calls to a web api, where the bulk of the wait time is waiting for data to come back, which I would like to do asynchronously. Then after the data is fetched, I want to return the data and store it in a variable. How would I go about doing this?

Below is the non asynchronous code:

```
api_data = [{data_name: get_data(data_name)} for data_name in data_name_list]
```

Below is my attempted asynchronous solution:

```
async def get_api_data(data_name_list):
    api_data = [{data_name: get_data(data_name)} for data_name in data_name_list]
    await asyncio.wait(api_data)
    await conn.close()
    return api_data

data = get_api_data(data_name_list)
```

The problem is that the `api_data` gets returned as a `coroutine object`. Shouldn't it not return as a `coroutine object` since I close the connection? Is there a better way to turn my `non asynchronous code` into an `asynchronous solution`?

Comment: try making that last line `data = await get_api_data(data_name_list)`

Comment: I get the following error: namedtuple_TokenInfo:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'get_api_data' was never awaited
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback

Comment: `api_data` is not a coroutine then why are you passing it to `asyncio.wait` ?

Comment: if you want an api req to occur async then try using `aiohttp` lib instead of `requests` library

Comment: I don't have control over the request since I am using a python wrapper of the web api.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is indeed possible to fire off multiple requests and asynchronously wait for them. Because Python is traditionally a synchronous language, you have to be very careful about what libraries you use with asynchronous Python. Any library that blocks the main thread (such as `requests`) will break your entire asynchronicity. `aiohttp` is a common choice for asynchronously making web API calls in Python. What you want is to create a bunch of *future* objects inside a Python list and await it. A future is an object that represents a value that will eventually resolve to something.

EDIT: Since the function that actually makes the API call is synchronous and blocking and you don't have control over it, you will have to run that function in a separate thread.

```
import asyncio

async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    futures = [asyncio.ensure_future(loop.run_in_executor(None, get_data, data)) for data in data_name_list]
    await asyncio.gather(*futures) # wait for all the future objects to resolve
    # Do something with futures
    # ...


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
loop.close()
```

Please note that this is Python 3.6 code and might vary significantly from 3.7+ async code

Comment: You put in the API_URL as an argument, but I'm using a python api wrapper, which I'm assuming uses requests, to get the data. Can I still use this solution with that?

Comment: I see. In that case you need to run the function in a separate thread using something like `loop.run_in_executor`. I edited my answer accordingly

Comment: Your parenthesis and brackets don't match in the fifth line.

Comment: I got the code running, but now on the `await` part I am getting the error: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'relativedelta'`