# How do I make my list comprehension (and the function it calls) run asynchronously?

Tags: python, asynchronous

```
class Class1():
    def func1():
        self.conn.send('something')
        data = self.conn.recv()
        return data

class Class2():    
    def func2():
        [class1.func1() for class1 in self.classes]
```

How do I make that last line asynchronously in python? I've been googling but can't understand `async`/`await` and don't know which functions I should be putting `async` in front of. In my case, all the `class1.func1` need to send before any of them can receive anything. I was also seeing that `__aiter__` and `__anext__` need to be implemented, but I don't know how those are used in this context. Thanks!

Comment: Asychronous should only be composed of asychronous functions. Likewise, asychronous functions need be started within an ascychronous manager. They don't just run on their own, but must be managed for signals and such. Asychronous programming can get quite complicated.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrency.html .. https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html

Comment: @BobbyOcean so you're saying I would need to rewrite everything so it's asynchronous in order for that list comprehension to be asynchronous? I guess I could split up func1 into send and recv functions so I could call all the send first, then call all the recv...but that's definitely not ideal.

Comment: @wwii I tried looking through that documentation (first thing that pops up when you google python async), but don't understand how to use it. The code snippet above is a toy example to gain some clarification since the examples in the documentation keep using await asyncio.sleep(1)

Comment: Yes, you should really think of asynchornous programming as completely separate from regular python. Like what Mahsa Hassankashi says, if you include non-ascychronous functions in your code, then they will block your asychronous functions which defeats the purpose of writing them. In asychronous programming you are going to write async functions that call and use async-libraries, etc.

Comment: Hm..the thing is I only want that line to be asynchronous and I actually want everything else to block since this is all self-contained and I'm not making any requests like Mahsa said. I have class1 and class2 in the same process and the thing that class1.func1 is sending/receiving from in another process. It seems like it's all set up to be run asynchronously since class1/2's process can just send requests and wait until the other process processes all requests.

Comment: Also, if the solution is not to go async, what's a good solution for this?

Comment: `I tried looking through that documentation ..., but don't understand how to use it.` - Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Answer (score 0):

> It is indeed possible to fire off multiple requests and asynchronously
>   wait for them. Because Python is traditionally a synchronous language,
>   you have to be very careful about what libraries you use with
>   asynchronous Python. Any library that blocks the main thread (such as
>   requests) will break your entire asynchronicity. aiohttp is a common
>   choice for asynchronously making web API calls in Python. What you
>   want is to create a bunch of future objects inside a Python list and
>   await it. A future is an object that represents a value that will
>   eventually resolve to something.
>
> EDIT: Since the function that actually makes the API call is
>   synchronous and blocking and you don't have control over it, you will
>   have to run that function in a separate thread.

[Async List Comprehensions in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57263090/async-list-comprehensions-in-python)

```
import asyncio

async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    futures = [asyncio.ensure_future(loop.run_in_executor(None, get_data, data)) for data in data_name_list]
    await asyncio.gather(*futures) # wait for all the future objects to resolve
    # Do something with futures
    # ...


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
loop.close()
```

Comment: I'm not using any web APIs